# лучшая правктика организации acl для конечного пользователя

Tags: php, symfony, best-practice, acl

какая лучшая практика оганизации ACL реализации\существующий модуль(бандл) для системы где права можно редактировать для конкретного пользователя

пример: среди пользователей таких ролей как менеджер, администратор, пользователь. Нужно чтоб в один менеджер имел частичные права на функционал админа, а другой менеджер был ограничен в правах менеджера но он менеджер а не простой пользователь.

из своей реализации вижу только мапинг в бд всех действий\роутов для конкретного пользователя. где группа пользователя это только базовый набор  доступной ему функциональности который в дальнейшем можно править.

Comment: один одно, другой другое. Логично, что и группы должны быть разными. user, power user, archive manager, network manager, etc

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов возможно мой вопрос сформулирован не понятно - но ваш комментарий не уместен. заказчик хочет лично редактировать права конечного пользователя

Comment: Всегда можете поискать готовые решения для своей платформы. Если достаточно role-based-access-control, то шансы найти велики. Более изощрённые методы авторизации обычно уже стоют каких-то денег.

Answer (score 1):

если никто не против, за неимением альтернатив набросаю свое видение данной реализации.
расширение ACL. где полномочия не статические для каждой роли а берутся из БД при аутентификации и дальше кешируются.

Comment: Поделитесь, как планируете проверять доступ к конкретным контроллерам? Voter? Firewall?